# How can I route my pages so that I am serving up slightly different content by subdomain in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, subdomain

I have a web application that is going to be used for two large companies. The app consists of a main static "company website" and the app itself. Only the static site needs to be separate, and of the 10 pages only 3 of them need to be company-specific. So I have this:

```
app/views/info (static area)
...about.html.erb
...company1_faq.html.erb
...company2_faq.html.erb
...company1_index.html.erb
...company2_index.html.erb
...company1_pricing.html.erb
...company2_pricing.html.erb
...privacy.html.erb
...license.html.erb
...terms.html.erb
```

I want to split these out by subdomain, then redirect based on subdomain for just these actions. However, I would like to strip the subdomain out of the URL also, which I don't know how to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Railscasts is always my first stop so I did follow Ryan's directions ;-)

Since I only need it for one controller, this is the rest of what I did and it's working great:

At the top of `info_controller.rb`:

```
before_filter :redirect_to_subdomain_page, only: [:index, :about, :pricing, :faq]
```

Then at the bottom:

```
private

def redirect_to_subdomain_page
  render "#{request.subdomain}_#{params[:action]}"
end
```

Perfect! It preserves the regular URL also.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the subdomain through the [Request object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object)

Like so:

```
request.subdomain
```

You could then put the partials in different folders

```
app/views/info/company1
app/views/info/company2
```

And then render them based on the subdomain.

```
<%= render "info/#{@subdomain}/faq" %>
```